# How to exclude a specific file in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have written below code in htaccess

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_-]+).php$ http://www.domain.com/myfile.php?page=inc-$1.php [NC]

I don't want the index.php file to be rewritten - it should open normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following code, to exclude all existing files (like index.php):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_-]+).php$ http://www.domain.com/myfile.php?page=inc-$1.php [NC]
```

or to exclude only `index.php` you can use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*/)?index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_-]+).php$ http://www.domain.com/myfile.php?page=inc-$1.php [NC]
```

Comment: You mean  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-index.php will allow to open index.php on regular way. right ? Thanks

Comment: No, `!-index.php` is not valid. `-f` means that the file exists and `!-f` means that the file doesn't exist.

Comment: I added another method you could use.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* this is what you're asking:

> "I want to allow the index.php file to
>   be served normally, but all other
>   requests follow this rewrite..."

To keep the index file from being redirected, you need a RewriteCond before the rule:

```
RewriteCond $1 !index\.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_-]+).php$ http://www.domain.com/myfile.php?page=inc-$1.php [NC]
```

Comment: Edited above to allow greater range of matches - took out the ^ and $