# Redirect requests from root/[...] to root/pages/[...](.php) via htaccess Rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to redirect all requests from `root/test.php` to `root/pages/test`
I already managed to eleminate the need for the .php extension by inserting ...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

... into my htaccess.
But how can I additionally achieve that all pages are actually stored in /pages?
I tried to change `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php` to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/$1.php` but that only works if I have a file with the same name in my webroot.

The reason for this is, that I dont want to have all my pages in the webroot folder since there are a lot of pages and I want to keep my root folder 'clean'.

Thx already!

Comment: I tried to add `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/$1.php [NC,L]`, but that triggers `root/pages/pages/pages/pages/pages/pages/pages/pages/pages/pages/pages/pages/pages/pages/pages/pages/pages/pages/pages/test.php`

Comment: `RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.php$ /pages/$1.php` also gives that same huge URL. I think that this is because the index.php itself gets redirected. May this be the issue?
If so: How to ignore the /index.php?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5185461/10955263

Comment: @04FS Tanks! That solves 50% of my problem. But I still can't get the whole Rewrite to work ... :/